# Change INT to Percent in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have this expression I would like to change the results to Percent

=""""& INT(Fields!Field.Value*100)/100 & """"

as now the results display .98 and I would like to see 98%

Answer (score 0):

Right click your column and select "Text Box Properties..."

You'll notice a tab called "Number".  Click on that tab.

You'll notice a list of categories.  One of those categories is called "Percentage".  Click on that category.

This will automatically change your value to a percentage.  For example, if your value is 0.98, it will show as 98%.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is a custom expression

Comment: If you have the expression =INT(Fields!Field.Value*100)/100 with those text box property changes, it should show up as a percentage.

Comment: Are you doing this expression?:
=""""& INT(Fields!Field.Value*100)/100 & """"

If so, try getting rid of the double-quotes on each side.  That way, it will get treated as a number and not a string.  The textbox property change should work on that.